When posting, the color will change according to the title. NEXTJS
                                    <Select
                                        id="countries"
                                        required
                                        onChange={(e) => setTask(e.target.value)}
                                        className=" w-full max-w-xs border-none border-inherit bg-blue-400 outline-none text-white rounded-2xl font-semibold"
                                    >
                                        <option >Banner</option> //==>THIS HAS TO BE RED
                                        <option >Illustration</option>//===>THIS HAS TO BE GREEN
                                        <option >Video</option>//ETC
                                        <option >UI UX</option>//ETC
                                    </Select>//

When I choose 1 option and onClick on button. It will post and title will be what I choose. I need to make it different background colors each of it. Sorry for bad English . Can you guys show me little example. I will appreciate it .
